# method doesn't override from its superclass- swift

Tags: ios, swift, overriding

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "ChecklistItem", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    return cell }
```

There's an error saying: method doesn't override from its superclass. I've deleted the "override"  but still not working. 
These are the source code from a book and it is said this is right syntax. So I want to know why I had this error?

Comment: What are you using UIViewController or UITableViewController? 
If using UIViewController then you need to extend UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Rock is likely pointing you in the right direction. If you are using UITableViewController, then you can override the method (it is defined in UITableViewController. Otherwise if you are just subclassing a UIViewController and extension with UITableViewDelegate, there is nothing to override. The “not working” might suggest that the table’s delegate wasn’t set. This suggests you’re using UIViewController and you need to connect the delegate (probably the dataSource too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swift 3

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "ChecklistItem", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "ChecklistItem", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        return cell 
}
```

In this code you have written remove extra **IndexPath** in parameter list.

*It should be*

> cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

*Not*

**cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell**

> Error is because compiler does'nt able to see such a method in base
>   class.